# How to download Gmail attachment to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

I'm trying to do an automation by using the Google Apps Script, and I'm having some trouble. That's why I need it.

1 - The script must identify the subject of an email.

2 - If the subject has a specific word, the script downloads the attachment.

3 - But before it downloads the attachment, the script should read the subject of the email and look in Google Drive if there is a folder with the same name of the subject.

4 - If the folder already exists, the script just downloads the file to this folder in Google Drive.

5 - Else, the script creates a folder with the same name of the email subject and then downloads the attachment to this folder.

Comment: Please show what  you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an attempt at this script, I'd recommend sharing it when posting a question and also pointing out the issues you are running into.

In any case, I'll share some documentation and ideas to help you achieve this.

1. Start by listing the messages you will be using for your automation. I'd recommend having a look at the Gmail API method [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list). The response of this method should contain an array called `messages` which you can loop through for the next requirements.
2. From the list of `messages` returned, you can find the subject of a message by accessing the attribute `message.payload.headers`. `headers` is a "name/value" type of array, if you loop through its contents, one of the "names" should be "Subject". Now you can store the subject on a variable to work with it and determine if it meets your criteria. To download a message attachment, you can use the Gmail API method [users.messages.attachments.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments/get).
3. With the full subject retrieved in `2`, you can search on a specific folder in Drive to see if a sub-folder with that name exists. To do that I'd recommend having a look at the Drive API method [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and use the parameter `q` to enter the search criteria. **Example**, to search for a folder named `SUBJECT_NAME_OF_FOLDER`, located inside another folder with id `PARENT_FOLDER_DRIVE_ID`, my `q` parameter value would look similar to `'PARENT_FOLDER_DRIVE_ID' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = 'SUBJECT_NAME_OF_FOLDER'`.
4. If a folder with your criteria is returned from `3`, then you can retrieve that folder ID from the response array `files[n].id`. With this ID, you can call Drive API [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), setting the `mimeType` according to the message attachment `mimeType` and the `parent` parameter will be the ID you found from the search in `3`.
5. If your search hasn't returned results, then most likely the folder with that specific name (at least in the location specified) does not exist, then you can create a new folder by calling Drive API [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) making sure to set the `mimeType` parameter as `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`. After creating the folder you can store the newly created ID and repeat `4` using this ID.

Hope it helps. Cheers!